# Javascript Binding Function to Shadow DOM and Custom Elements

Tags: javascript, binding, polymer, shadow-dom

I am using [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org) on a project. I have a general custom-element that encapsulates my whole project, let's call it `<my-app></my-app>`. I want that whenever a button (`<paper-button>`, `<paper-item>`, `<my-custom-clickable-item>`, ... ) a sound is played. The playing of the sound is no problem, but I don't quite know how to effectively bind the function to all the elements I want.

I know there's a way to [fire custom events](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#fire), but if `<my-custom-clickable-item>` would be inside another element `<another-custom-element>`, I would need to catch it there and pass it through to `<my-app>`, which isn't really a good solution either.

Next to only binding a sound to the button, it would be ideal that depending on whether the item has a `disabled` attribute another sound would be played.

Here is some sample code of how my app sort of looks.

```
<polymer-element name="my-app">
    <template>
        <audio id="mySound" style="display: none;">
            <source src="assets/mySound.wav" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
        <paper-button>I make sound!</paper-button>
        <my-custom-clickable-item>I make sound as well!</my-custom-clickable-item>

        <paper-button disabled>I should make another sound though...</paper-button>

        <just-another-element></just-another-element>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-app', {
            makeNoise: function(){
                this.$.mySound.play();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="just-another-element">
    <template>
        <p>I am another custom element, with other buttons!</p>
        <paper-button>Sound sound sound</paper-button>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: If your <my-custom-clickable-item> fires an event, it should bubble up to the root of your app or, <my-app>.  If you set up a listener on my app and fire a custom event in <my-custom-clickable-item>, the listener in <my-app> should catch it.

Comment: @user2210274: and how about the `<paper-button>` (or whatever else) in the `<just-another-element>`?

Comment: Since you want different sounds to play, on fire you could attach a custom object when you fire the event with the correct sound then handle it the same way in the parent element.  `var temp = { sound = 'path' }; this.fire('customEvent', temp);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events can bubble up without problem, even inside other elements. And you can use the `fire` method to add details about the sender item, like if it's disabled or not. Then in the main event handle, you can play different sounds according to that details.

Here you have a quick example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <title>seed-element Demo</title>
  <script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/core-elements.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">

</head>

<body>

  <my-app></my-app>


  <polymer-element name="my-app">
    <template>
      <style>
        paper-button[disabled] {
          pointer-events: all !important;
        }
      </style>
      <audio id="soundWhenEnabled" style="display: none;">
        <source src="assets/mySoundEnabled.wav" type="audio/wav">
      </audio>
      <audio id="soundWhenDisabled" style="display: none;">
        <source src="assets/mySoundDisabled.wav" type="audio/wav">
      </audio>
      <paper-button id="b1" raised on-click="{{onClick}}">I make sound!</paper-button>
      <my-custom-clickable-item id="b2" on-click="{{onClick}}">I make sound as well!</my-custom-clickable-item>

      <paper-button id="b3" disabled raised on-click="{{onClick}}">I should make another sound though...</paper-button>

      <just-another-element></just-another-element>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer('my-app', {
        eventDelegates: {
          //click: 'onClick',
          sound: 'makeNoise'
        },
        onClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
          console.log("Click "+sender.hasAttribute('disabled'))
          this.fire('sound', {id:sender.id, disabled: sender.hasAttribute('disabled')});
        },
        makeNoise: function(event, detail, sender){
          console.log(detail)
          if (detail.disabled) {
            //this.$.soundWhenDisabled.play();
            alert("I make noise disabled");
          } else {
            //this.$.soundWhenEnabled.play();
            alert("I make noise enabled");
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <polymer-element name="just-another-element">
    <template>
      <p>I am another custom element, with other buttons!</p>
      <paper-button id="b4" raised on-click="{{onClick}}">Sound sound sound</paper-button>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer('just-another-element', {
        onClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
          console.log("Click "+sender.hasAttribute('disabled'))
          this.fire('sound', {id:sender.id, disabled: sender.hasAttribute('disabled')});
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

</body>
</html>
```

The Plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SOwYbU3Fvlhp0MgvM60H?p=preview

I hope it helps :) As usual, don't hesitate to ask for precisions

Comment: I like it, but as I mentioned it would be easy if I don't need to manually attach the `onClick`-function to each button, since this is prone to error (eg forgetting it). Is it possible, or is it better to make a custom element that just has eg a `<paper-button>` in it, but with the `onClick`?

Comment: In that case I would do a custom `<my-button>` containing only a `<paper-button>` element with a `click` on its `eventDelegates` pointing to the `onClick` function that fires the `sound` event.

Comment: I'll try to do an example of it later today